# Get range of columns with specific value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I wasn't sure how to title this question, but I've got an Oracle table that has a column for each day of the week. These represent the days a business is open. The values in these columns is either 'Y' or 'N'. This is how the table was setup years ago and I am unable to change it.

```
ID | MONDAY | TUESDAY | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY | SATURDAY | SUNDAY
1      Y         Y          Y          Y          Y        N          N
2      N         Y          Y          Y          Y        Y          N
```

I need to be able to query this table and get results like the following, but am not sure where to even start.

```
ID  |     DAYS_OPEN
1      MONDAY - FRIDAY
2      TUESDAY - SATURDAY
```

Is this even possible in a query or will I need to use a function? If a function would make it easier, I'd be fine with that solution as well.

Comment: All combinations are possible?
I mean can the opened days be from Thursday to Monday for example and what should be the result in this case? THURSDAY - MONDAY?
Also can the result be split into two or more periods like MONDAY-WEDNESDAY + FRIDAY-SATURDAY?

Comment: @Dornaut yes, all combinations are possible, although the majority will either be Monday - Friday or Monday - Sunday.

This table also contains a column for each month which I will need to apply similar logic to. I just figured I'd start with the easier scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found easier solution:

```sql
replace(
      trim( 
        '.' from
        replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
            regexp_replace(
                   decode(MONDAY    ,'Y','1','.') ||
                   decode(TUESDAY   ,'Y','2','.') || 
                   decode(WEDNESDAY ,'Y','3','.') || 
                   decode(THURSDAY  ,'Y','4','.') || 
                   decode(FRIDAY    ,'Y','5','.') || 
                   decode(SATURDAY  ,'Y','6','.') || 
                   decode(SUNDAY    ,'Y','7','.')                   
                  ,'(\d)\d*(\d)','\1-\2')
           ,'1','MONDAY')
           ,'2','TUESDAY')
           ,'3','WEDNESDAY')
           ,'4','THURSDAY')
           ,'5','FRIDAY')
           ,'6','SATURDAY')
           ,'7','SUNDAY')
        ),'.',',')
```

Full example:

```sql
with t(ID, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY) as (
   select 1,'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'N', 'N' from dual union all
   select 2,'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'Y', 'N' from dual union all
   select 3,'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N' ,'Y', 'Y' from dual
)
select
   id
  ,replace(
      trim( 
        '.' from
        replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
            regexp_replace(
                   decode(MONDAY    ,'Y','1','.') ||
                   decode(TUESDAY   ,'Y','2','.') || 
                   decode(WEDNESDAY ,'Y','3','.') || 
                   decode(THURSDAY  ,'Y','4','.') || 
                   decode(FRIDAY    ,'Y','5','.') || 
                   decode(SATURDAY  ,'Y','6','.') || 
                   decode(SUNDAY    ,'Y','7','.')                   
                  ,'(\d)\d*(\d)','\1-\2')
           ,'1','MONDAY')
           ,'2','TUESDAY')
           ,'3','WEDNESDAY')
           ,'4','THURSDAY')
           ,'5','FRIDAY')
           ,'6','SATURDAY')
           ,'7','SUNDAY')
        ),'.',',')
     as sch
from t;
```

Result:

```
        ID SCH
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
         1 MONDAY-FRIDAY
         2 TUESDAY-SATURDAY
         3 MONDAY,WEDNESDAY-THURSDAY,SATURDAY-SUNDAY
```

Edit: expanding on the original answer to apply the same process to months of the year. I had to wrap the month number in square brackets in the decode. Then in the regexp_replace, I specified a non-matching list (period and whitespace).

Here's the full example:

```sql
with t(ID, JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER ) as (
   select 1,'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'N', 'N', 'Y','Y','Y','Y','Y' from dual union all
   select 2,'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'N' ,'N', 'N', 'N','Y','Y','Y','Y' from dual union all
   select 3,'N', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'N' ,'Y', 'Y', 'N','N','N','Y','N' from dual union all
   select 4,'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'N', 'Y' ,'N', 'Y', 'N','Y','N','Y','N' from dual
)
select
   id,
regexp_replace(
          trim( '.' from
            replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
            regexp_replace(
                       decode(JANUARY    ,'Y','01','.') ||
                       decode(FEBRUARY   ,'Y','02','.') || 
                       decode(MARCH      ,'Y','03','.') || 
                       decode(APRIL      ,'Y','04','.') || 
                       decode(MAY        ,'Y','05','.') || 
                       decode(JUNE       ,'Y','06','.') || 
                       decode(JULY       ,'Y','07','.') || 
                       decode(AUGUST     ,'Y','08','.')|| 
                       decode(SEPTEMBER  ,'Y','09','.')|| 
                       decode(OCTOBER    ,'Y','10','.')|| 
                       decode(NOVEMBER   ,'Y','11','.')|| 
                       decode(DECEMBER   ,'Y','12','.')                  
                      ,'(\d\d)\d*(\d\d)','\1-\2')
               ,'01','Jan')
               ,'02','Feb')
               ,'03','Mar')
               ,'04','Apr')
               ,'05','May')
               ,'06','Jun')
               ,'07','Jul')
               ,'08','Aug')
               ,'09','Sep')
               ,'10','Oct')
               ,'11','Nov')
               ,'12','Dec')
              )
            ,'\.+',', ') MNTHS
            from t;
```

and the results:

```
ID  MNTHS
1   Jan-May, Aug-Dec 
2   Jan-Apr, Sep-Dec 
3   Mar, Jun-Jul, Nov
4   Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Sep, Nov
```

Comment: Both of your solutions work, but this can easily be added to an existing query so I'm going with this route. I can also easily adapt this to find the months of operation too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you suggest how to change the regexp_replace pattern to do this same process when you have double digit values (month numbers)? The current pattern is splitting on first & last adjacent digits but when I change this over from days of week to months, then October - December are double digit month numbers.

Comment: @dstnrgrs 2 digits months would be much easier, ie 01-12

Comment: @dstnrgrs I've simplified your query - please check it out

Comment: The two digit months make so much more sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have the data in a lousy format.  You can use a giant `case` expression:

```
(case MONDAY || TUESDAY || WEDNESDAY || THURSDAY || FRIDAY || SATURDAY || SUNDAY
    when 'YYYYYNN' then 'MONDAY - FRIDAY'
    when 'NYYYYYN' then 'TUESDAY - SATURDAY'
    else 'Something else!'
 end)
```

There are only 2^7 = 128 possible combinations, so this is actually possible with a giant `case`.  You could also put the values in a reference table and join to that.

Comment: I agree the data is in a lousy format. I hadn't considered a CASE statement for each possibility, and it would be a giant CASE statement for sure. Unfortunately this same table has a column for each month that I'll need to apply similar logic to get a range of months. I was hoping there was a simpler way to do it that I just am not thinking of.

Comment: @dstnrgrs . . . I'm not sure that the "simpler" method is actually simpler. I would suggest a reference table.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all you need to transform your data using PIVOT:

```sql
with t(ID, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY) as (
   select 1,'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'N', 'N' from dual union all
   select 2,'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'Y', 'N' from dual
)
,tpivot as (
  select 
    id, 
    weekday, 
    decode(weekday,'MONDAY',1, 'TUESDAY', 2, 'WEDNESDAY', 3, 'THURSDAY', 4, 'FRIDAY', 5, 'SATURDAY', 6, 'SUNDAY',7) weekday_n,
    val
  from t
  unpivot
    (
    val for weekday in (MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY)
    ) v
)
select * from tpivot;
```

Result:

```sql
        ID WEEKDAY    WEEKDAY_N V
---------- --------- ---------- -
         1 MONDAY             1 Y
         1 TUESDAY            2 Y
         1 WEDNESDAY          3 Y
         1 THURSDAY           4 Y
         1 FRIDAY             5 Y
         1 SATURDAY           6 N
         1 SUNDAY             7 N
         2 MONDAY             1 N
         2 TUESDAY            2 Y
         2 WEDNESDAY          3 Y
         2 THURSDAY           4 Y
         2 FRIDAY             5 Y
         2 SATURDAY           6 Y
         2 SUNDAY             7 N
```

2. Then you can filter days which have 'Y' in VAL column and aggregate them:

```sql
with t(ID, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY) as (
   select 1,'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'N', 'N' from dual union all
   select 2,'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'Y', 'N' from dual union all
   select 3,'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N' ,'Y', 'Y' from dual
)
,tpivot as (
  select 
    id, 
    weekday, 
    decode(weekday,'MONDAY',1, 'TUESDAY', 2, 'WEDNESDAY', 3, 'THURSDAY', 4, 'FRIDAY', 5, 'SATURDAY', 6, 'SUNDAY',7) weekday_n,
    val
  from t
  unpivot
    (
    val for weekday in (MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY)
    ) v
)
, filtered as (
   select 
      id,
      weekday,
      weekday_n,
      weekday_n - row_number()over(partition by id order by weekday_n) rn,
      val
   from tpivot
   where val='Y'
)
, agg as (
   select
      id, 
      min(weekday)keep(dense_rank first order by weekday_n) d_first,
      min(weekday)keep(dense_rank last order by weekday_n) d_last,
      count(*) cnt
   from filtered
   group by id,rn
)
select * from agg;
```

Result:

```sql
        ID D_FIRST   D_LAST           CNT
---------- --------- --------- ----------
         1 MONDAY    FRIDAY             5
         2 TUESDAY   SATURDAY           5
         3 MONDAY    MONDAY             1
         3 WEDNESDAY THURSDAY           2
         3 SATURDAY  SUNDAY             2
```

3. And last step is to aggregate all values by ID:

```sql
with t(ID, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY) as (
   select 1,'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'N', 'N' from dual union all
   select 2,'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y' ,'Y', 'N' from dual union all
   select 3,'Y', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'N' ,'Y', 'Y' from dual
)
,tpivot as (
  select 
    id, 
    weekday, 
    decode(weekday,'MONDAY',1, 'TUESDAY', 2, 'WEDNESDAY', 3, 'THURSDAY', 4, 'FRIDAY', 5, 'SATURDAY', 6, 'SUNDAY',7) weekday_n,
    val
  from t
  unpivot
    (
    val for weekday in (MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY)
    ) v
)
, filtered as (
   select 
      id,
      weekday,
      weekday_n,
      weekday_n - row_number()over(partition by id order by weekday_n) rn,
      val
   from tpivot
   where val='Y'
)
, agg as (
   select
      id, 
      min(weekday_n)keep(dense_rank first order by weekday_n) d_first_n,
      min(weekday)keep(dense_rank first order by weekday_n) d_first,
      min(weekday)keep(dense_rank last order by weekday_n) d_last,
      count(*) cnt
   from filtered
   group by id,rn
)
select 
  id,
  listagg(
    case when cnt=1 then d_first
         else d_first||'-'||d_last
    end,
    ','
  ) within group(order by d_first_n) sched
from agg
group by id;
```

Result:

```sql
        ID SCHED
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------
         1 MONDAY-FRIDAY
         2 TUESDAY-SATURDAY
         3 MONDAY,WEDNESDAY-THURSDAY,SATURDAY-SUNDAY
```

Comment: This looks promising. I'm going to try to wrap my head around this. I'll let you know if it works out for me. Thanks.